# javascript remove required attribute is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am using the folloing function to remove the required attribute from check boxes in case if any check box is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aboveage5").click(function(){
            if ($('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]').val() != "" ) {
                $('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]').removeAttr('required');
                 //Slide Down Effect  
            } else {           
                $('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]').prop('required',true);    //Slide Up Effect
            }
         });            
    });
```

when I load the page and If I click on some of them before I hit the submit button everything is working fine. But If I don't make a selection and the check for requred fields indicate that I have to select any of the checkboxes is not working. I mean it is working it removes the required attribute but wen I hit submit nothing is happening, I mean a text field is required still coming but not saying which field in the code I can see that the attribute is being removed but it is not submitting anything, it stays on the same page.

this is the input:

```
<input type="checkbox" required="required" class="aboveage5"  name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]" value="Val 1"  />val 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" required="required" class="aboveage5"  name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]" value="Val 2"  />Val 2<br />
```

Comment: You should use `.prop('required', false)` instead of `removeAttr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:checked` pseudo-selector to match checked and unchecked boxes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".aboveage5").click(function () {
        $('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]:not(:checked)').removeAttr('required');
        $('input[name="tipo_de_producto_que_fabrica[]"]:checked').attr('required', true);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/cwTVV/3/)

Comment: thanks Barmar, you are the man, this works excelent I have somewhere else error which I will investigate but it is working fine.